# Call to 'substring' is redundant

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lint

I've created simple code to reverse an equation, but two lines are highlighted by `lint` in IntelliJ IDEA. Exact message is

> Call to 'substring' is redundant

```
final String equation = "20+3*475-2-1*4";

final int size = equation.length();
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
int right = size;
for (int i = size - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    switch (equation.charAt(i)) {
        case '+': case '-': case '*':
            sb.append(equation.substring(i + 1, right));  // this line
            sb.append(equation.charAt(i));
            right = i;
    }
}
if (right != 0) {
    sb.append(equation.substring(0, right));   // and this line
}
```

I haven't ever faced with a situation when `lint` highlights something without a reason. But now have no idea why these calls are redundant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simplify the call to this:

```
sb.append(equation, i + 1, right);
```

This avoids an explicit intermediate string construction, allowing the implementation to copy the desired part of "equation" directly.

Comment: The only answer mentioned that intermediate string won't be created

Comment: It avoids *necessarily* constructing an intermediate string. An implementation of `StringBuilder` could, if it wanted, construct a substring. Passing in the string and the indices leaves it up to the implementor to decide; doing the substring yourself takes away the opportunity to do it without the substring.

Comment: Checked with openjdk, re-worded anyway.

Answer (score 4):

That's because StringBuilder append is overlaoded with a function, that also takes start and end index like substring.

So instead of using

```
sb.append(equation.substring(i + 1, right));
```

you can just use

```
sb.append(equation, i + 1, right);
```

Answer (score 1):

A String is a CharSequence, and StringBuffer has an append() method taking exactly the same arguments as substring(). You can eliminate the call to substring().